# How to make order apply only to non-null records yet get all records?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to order the result based on the condition.

**For example**

```
@redeemables = @business.redeemables.order(expiry_date: :desc)
```

I want all redeemables with `expiry_date => nil` first than redeemables order by desc

In other means, redeemables which have `exipry_date < Date.current` should come in bottom in the order.

How I can do this? Thanks

Comment: I am a little bit surprised, nil values should show on top when ordering desc. What DB do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is:

```
@redeemables = @business.redeemables.order("-expiry_date asc")
```

- This will give you exactly **reverse result** of (expiry_date: asc)
- It means **descending ordered by expiry_date with null first**

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PostgreSQL there's the nice `NULLS FIRST` (vs. `NULLS LAST`) statement, but there's the standard SQL way of doing this (`CASE` works basically always), because `relation + relation` will trigger eager loading, which you probably don't want to happen.

```
@redeemables = @business.redeemables.order('(CASE WHEN expiry_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) desc, expiry_date desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

```
@redeemables_without_expiry = @business.redeemables.where("expiry_date IS NULL")
@redeemables_with_expiry = @business.redeemables.where("expiry_date IS NOT NULL").order(expiry_date: :desc)

@redeemables = @redeemables_without_expiry + @redeemables_with_expiry
```

Comment: Thanks but I think it's not a good solution to run 2 query for order only

Comment: No problem bro. Just a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@redeemables = @business.redeemables.sort_by {|r| "#{r.expiry_date.blank?} #{r.desc}" }
```

Whats its basically doing is sorting by a concatenated string of whether the expiry date is blank (`true`/`false`) and the description. (e.g. `false item_description`).

If you want to change the sort order of the nil `expiry_dates`, you can do the following:

```
@redeemables = @business.redeemables.sort_by {|r| "#{r.expiry_date.present?} #{r.desc}" }
```